# Trouble Installing as Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows 7 installed, and am attempting to set up elementary os alongside windows. When I attempt to set up the partition, there seems to be only free space, I cannot see my windows partitions. GParted only sees free space as well.

Comment: Are you trying to use the built in Disk Management tool in Win7? It is a possibility that your drive is locked and therefor not able to be seen properly. Check your BIOS and make sure any lower level encryption software is not running.